# read yaml parameter in C++

Tags: c++, roslaunch, yaml, rosparam, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm experiencing an issue in using the parameter server:

1. I start a roscore so that I get only one master on this machine.
2. I set a global param manually, say:

   rosparam set /test/m '{"id0": 0, "id1": 1}'
3. I start one of my launchfile whose short version is:

I get:

```
roslaunch mypckg mylaunch.launch
... logging to /home/flowers/.ros/log/08d803da-74d2-11e4-9a51-a01d480daef0/roslaunch-zbook-4127.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://zbook:55760/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
```

4. In the code of "mynode" I read this param:

   ```
                string m;
                if(!nh.getParam("/test/map", m))
                    ROS_ERROR("Failed to read 'map' on param server");
   ```
5. The above error is triggered, while rosparam get /thr/before still returns an existing value. It looks like I'm not reading params in the same namespace but I'm reading global parameters so I don't understand...

What are the PARAMETERS listed in the SUMMARY? Only parameters defined in the launch file or all available parameters on the server?

What am I missing? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198274/read-yaml-parameter-in-c++/) by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 454 on 2014-11-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-11-25**:
What is the output of `rosparam list`? You can try that at various points to see what the parameters are or how they're changing (using `rosparam get`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've modified my question to match the real problem and answer to it. Reading a yamlis quite heavy in C++, here's a way to read a map of arrays for instance:

```
                XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue symbols;

                if(!ros::param::get("/thr/symbols", symbols))
                    ROS_ERROR("Failed to read symbols on param server");

                ROS_ASSERT(symbols.getType()==XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeStruct);
                for (XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::iterator i=symbols.begin(); i!=symbols.end(); ++i) {
                    ROS_ASSERT(i->second.getType()==XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray);
                    for(int j=0; j<i->second.size(); ++j) {
                        ROS_ASSERT(i->second[j].getType()==XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeDouble);
                    }
                }
```

With YAML being:

```
object0: [0.1280805148444952, -0.2574350304851667]
table: [-0.019239830108468144]
object1: [-0.12373553201812965, -0.2581443366277866, 0.12297468008504482, 0.0405834453536516, 0.9474896873206372, -0.026972527372781926]
arm: [0.9303491449393159]
eye: [0.12397546355498722 -0.37202872219628474]
```

Sorry for editing 1000 times :)

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2014-11-26**:
Mmm, yaml-cpp makes yaml in C++ soooo much easier and less ugly!

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-11-26**:
Would it be really easier? This is not longer than the minimal code to iterate on two nested datastructures... the assert are for safety but obviously optional

**Comment by [Tommi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23616/tommi/) on 2015-09-07**:
That code looks terrible.

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2017-05-26**:
yaml-cpp is nice, but they've made horrible things with their versioning, so now we have ROS packages depending on 0.3, while other packages depend on 0.5, which can't be easily installed alongside... this is hell... guys from ETH tried to make it easier: https://github.com/ethz-asl/yaml_cpp_catkin

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you create nh in your code? If you declare it with

```
   ros:: NodeHandle nh("~")
```

then it'll be in the private namespace of your node. Honestly that's the only source of this problem that I can think of. Also make sure you're spelling the names correctly :)

To test the namespaces, you can use the NodeHandle method resolveName (see http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a9eab8c5ff7ca9d3468d2a35dcd84ae40).

**EDIT**

Editing since the original question changed. I tried the following:

```
>> rosparam set /test/m '{"id0":0, "id1":1}'    
>> rosparam get /          
     test:   
      m: {id0: 0, id1: 1}
>> rosparam get /test/m
     {id0: 0, id1: 1}
>> rosparam get /test/m/id0
     0
>> rosparam get /test/m/id1
     1
```

This is explained in http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_set, and it basically means that when you give a YAML string to rosparam set, it gets converted in a dictionary of parameters. You can see this behaviour if you do:

```
>> rosparam set -v /test/m '{"id0":0, "id1":1}'
set parameter [/test/m/id0] to [0]
set parameter [/test/m/id1] to [1]
```

Therefore the parameter you are looking for in your code (/test//m) doesn't exist as a string, but it's a dictionary! If you want to set a parameter to a string representing a YAML line, you can do something like:

```
>> rosparam set -v /test/m "\"{'id0':0, 'id1':1}\""
set parameter [/test/m] to [{'id0':0, 'id1':1}]
```

Even though it looks ugly :)

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) on 2014-11-26**:
Yes I see. Well actually this is very useful to be able to read this as a dictionary. In my case I intended to ive the string to yaml-cpp so using the xml-rpc datastructures is also good, though heavy (as any C++ code :)